# Game sprite animation

Tags: javascript, animation, sprite, frames, sprite-sheet

I am making a game and I want to animate my character(attacking, walking, etc) but I don't have an idea on how to do it. I know it is not for loop because if it is, the animation will play in an instant you won't be able to see it. I have downloaded a sample sprite sheet and I will test on it once I learn how to do it.

Comment: Show what you tried. Google javascript animation sprite tutorial

Comment: What is the question ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can obtain sprites animation using [CSS3's steps() function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/timing-function) where supported. Or a plain javascript approach using timers (`setTimeout`, `setInterval`).

Here a simple examples of both: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/hCeuG

However for the JS part, it's better if you have a single game loop where you update your animation, that it's just an example. You can find a very deep explanation about javascript game loop here: http://nokarma.org/2011/02/02/javascript-game-development-the-game-loop/index.html

Comment: Thanks for this! I actually don't want to use gaming libraries because I have to learn it first (i feel like it's a waste of time trying to understand most of the library) before I could make my game.

Comment: I expected that from your question, that's why I didn't provide any game library but example and explanation of the base concept. :) Hope it helps! Take a look to the game loop article especially, it's fundamental. Even if you're using the cavas to draw the image, the approach to "animate" in JS from a sprite sheet is quite the same.

Comment: I have a question, where do I put the setInterval? Do I put in the update()? Will that affect the interval?

Comment: I used `setInterval` to makes a simple example about how to use a spritesheet in JS instead of CSS3. The best approach is have a "real" game loop, as described in the article I linked. In that case you will use `requestAnimationFrame` where available, that is a better choice. And you will have a more consistent frame rate.

Comment: I mean, if I press the attack button the animation will start, where do I put the animation?

Comment: If you take a look to the article above, you will notice that you have `Game.update` and `Game.draw` methods. The first contains the logic – update position for instance, or "state" of the sprite – the second is used to draw that on the screen. So you have a "neverending loop" that based on the state will draw the sprite. If you press attack button, then you will need to update this information in `Game.update`, and in the `Game.draw` you will draw that animation instead the default ones.

Answer (score 2):

there are making JS based gaming libraries available that exists for the sole purpose of making games easier. you should be using one of them.
I have worked on some of them and I like [CreateJS](http://www.createjs.com/) with extensive support of sounds and spritesheets.
in fact you can create spritesheets on fly using animations

Answer (score 0):

You can use Free sprites or try to make it with Photoshop ( if you are pro ! ) or [Sprite Maker](http://www.spriteland.com/sprites/sprite-maker.htm)  ( for Basic users ! )

for 3D Models you can use

Answer (score 0):

I was also in such situation.

[CreateJS](http://www.createjs.com/) was very much helpful for me.

This library has avery good documentation on handling sprite-sheet and bitmap animation.

EaselJS has examples with source code to show how to use the sprite sheet in your game.

Another blog which was helpful for sprite sheet manipulation was by [David Rousset: HTML5 Gaming: animating sprites in Canvas with EaselJS](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/davrous/archive/2011/07/21/html5-gaming-animating-sprites-in-canvas-with-easeljs.aspx)

I think these could be helpful for you